# find max value of a list with numpy nan

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, max

```
import numpy as np

print max([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4])
print max([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan])
print max([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4])
```

the first will print nan as list's max value

the second will print 4 as list's max value

the third will print 4 as list's max value

Is there a solution for this problem? Make all math function just ignore nan?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`np.nanmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) to ignore any NaNs:

```
In [57]: np.nanmax([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[57]: 4.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to speed up np.nanmax function ?