# How to find the min and max elements in a list that has nan in between

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column named "score". I am extracting all the elements from that column into a list. It has 'nan's in between. I wish to identify the min and max of elements before every 'nan' occurs.

I was looking into converting the column into a list, and traverse the list until I encounter an "nan". But how do I traverse back to find the min and max elements right before nan?

This is the code I wrote to convert a column of a dataframe into a list and then identify the "nan".

```
score_list = description_df['score'].tolist()
for i in score_list:
    print(i)
    if math.isnan(i):
        print("\n")
```

Suppose my data looks like this,

```
 11.03680137760893
 5.351482041139766
 10.10019513222711
 nan
 0.960990030082931
 nan
 6.46983084276682
 32.46794015293125
 nan
```

Then, I should be able to identify max as 11.03680137760893
and min as 5.351482041139766 before the occurrence of the first "nan", 0.960990030082931 as the min and max before the occurrence of second nan and after the occurrence of first nan, and 32.46794015293125 as max and 6.46983084276682 as min after the second 'nan' and before the third 'nan'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find max value of a list with numpy nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042424/find-max-value-of-a-list-with-numpy-nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups by testing missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `min` and `max` and last remove only missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df['score'].isna().cumsum())['score'].agg(['min','max']).dropna()
print (df)
            min        max
score                     
0      5.351482  11.036801
1      0.960990   0.960990
2      6.469831  32.467940
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting the min and max in a separate dataframe, But the min and max values need to be in the original dataframe with its 'score' column. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two variables called *min* and *max* that begin with a default value each time you find a nan and print them (or store).

```
import sys

score_list = description_df['score'].tolist()
max = sys.float_info.min
min = sys.float_info.max
for i in score_list:
    print(i)
    if math.isnan(i):
        print("max =", max, "min =", min, "\n")
        max = sys.float_info.min
        min = sys.float_info.max
    else:
        if i > max:
            max = i
        if i < min:
            min = i
```